# How to display text when hover over videos/images

Tags: javascript, html, css

My image and videos are blurred whenever they are hovered over. Now, I also want them to both blur and display text whenever I hover over. I have tried to use hover for both but only the blur part is applicable so far. I also want the text to be able to resize accordingly with the video box so that when scaling down, it will resize accordingly. Thank you very much !

Code so far:

```css
html{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size:62.5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1rem;
    z-index: 100;
}

.wrapper1{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start | center | flex-end;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

h4{
    display:block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-block-start: 0.83em;
    margin-block-end: 0.83em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
    z-index:50;
}

.type2{
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 10rem;
    margin-right: 10rem;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera */
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

body{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.main{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.wrapper{
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:auto;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}









@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px){
    .type2{
       display: none;
    }

    .type1{
        font-size: 24px;
    }
}


video{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    object-fit: contain;
}

.main-section{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 25%;

}

.main-section div{
    flex:1;
}



.vid_vertical{
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    width: 20%;
}

.vid_1{
    position: absolute;
    left: 25.5%;

    z-index: 1;

}

.vid_1:hover {
    filter:blur(10px);
}

.type_ins: hover{
    display: block;
}



.type_ins{
    font-size: 0.7vw;
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    z-index: 50 !important;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;    
}
.vid_2{
    positon: absolute;
    left: 50% ;
    z-index:2;
}

.vid_3{
    positon: absolute;
    left: 148%  ;
    z-index:3;

}

.vid_4{
    positon: absolute;
    left: 74%  ;
    z-index:3;

}

.vid_5{
    positon: absolute;
    left: 98%  ;
    z-index:3;

}

.vid_6{
    positon: absolute;
    left: 122.5%  ;
    z-index:3;

}


.img1{
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    width: 20%;
    left: 0;
    z-index:0;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,width=device-width">        
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Interactive story.css">
        <title>Interactive Storytelling</title>
       
    </head>

    <body>
      
        <div class="main">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="wrapper1">
                    <div class="type1">
                        <h4>2019</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="type2">
                         <h4>I came to Toronto in August 2018 so we (me and my friend)
                            adopted Hershey when we were still in our first year. <br>
                            Before adopting Hershey, we nearly got scammed by buying a dog with a cheaper price so we decided to adopt rather than buying.<br>
                            She was actually our second choice, the first one having a lot of medical issues so we had to move on.<br>
                            I think she chose us actually because of all the people who wanted her, we were the only one whom she didn't hiss at. </h4>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        <section>
            <div class="wrapper">
                
                <div class="main-section">
          
                   
                  
                    <video class="vid_vertical vid_1" autoplay loop muted preload playsinline>
                        <source src="IMG_1362.mp4" type="video/mp4">    
                    </video>

             

                
                    <video class="vid_vertical vid_2"  autoplay loop muted preload playsinline>
                        <source src="IMG_1364.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>

                    <video class="vid_vertical vid_3"  autoplay loop muted preload playsinline>
                        <source src="IMG_1832.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
                    
                    <video class="vid_vertical vid_4"  autoplay loop muted preload playsinline>
                        <source src="1080p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>

                    <video class="vid_vertical vid_5"  autoplay loop muted preload playsinline>
                        <source src="IMG_1381.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>

                    <video class="vid_vertical vid_6"  autoplay loop muted preload playsinline>
                        <source src="IMG_1391.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>






                    <img src="IMG_1275_2.jpg" class="img1">

                </div>
            </div>

        </section>
        
        </div>  

       
              

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="Interactive story.js"></script>

        <!-- <section>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="vid">
                    <iframe id="vid_vertical" class="vid_2" autoplay loop muted preload playsinline>
                        <source src="IMG_1363.MOV" type="video/mp4">
                    </iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section> -->


    </body>
```

Comment: Can you also share your code in Interactive story.js? Also you need a closing </html> tag

Comment: oh sorry currently it doesn't have anything in the js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ll need to have the text you want to show in the DOM first. You’ll probably also need to add a `<div>` wrapper around the `<video>`, because even though your hover effect works, `<video>` is a special element meant for playing videos and doesn’t support all interactions a more generic element can.

```html
<div class="vid_1_wrapper">
  <video class="vid_1">…</video>
  <div class="vid_1_text">My text</div>
</div>
```

```css
.vid_1_text {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none; /* don’t block video clicks */
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 150ms linear;
  top: 0; /* adjust "top" and "left" to taste */
}

.vid_1_wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.vid_1_wrapper:hover .vid_1 {
  filter: blur(10px);
}

.vid_1_wrapper:hover .vid_1_text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

By moving the `:hover` pseudoclass to a wrapper element, you can trigger multiple effects with the same interaction, including blurring the video and showing text at the same time.

This is just an example using your classes; to improve on this you’ll probably want to use more generic classes like `.video` and `.video-text` so you can reuse them.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the image and the "appear on hover" description in a div with the same dimensions of the image. Then, with some CSS, order the description to appear while hovering that div.

```
/* quick reset */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

/* relevant styles */
.img__wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 257px;
}

.img__description {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(29, 106, 154, 0.72);
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;

  /* transition effect. not necessary */
  transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
}

.img__wrap:hover .img__description {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```
<div class="img__wrap">
  <img class="img__img" src="http://placehold.it/257x200.jpg" />
  <p class="img__description">This image looks super neat.</p>
</div>
```